# Ways to insert and retrieve text from text fields from another program

Tags: c#, java, c++, web

I have a family member that runs his own shop. He's asked me to basically create a CRM system for him that communicates with his current inventory/invoice system because it does all that stuff well but it doesn't really let him look up customers well and manage his customers. His current system uses is a windows application but there is no way to interface with it. (Or not direct way). I was wondering what would be the best development solution from placing data into another program's text fields or retrieving from the text fields of the program?

Comment: I think a lot more information is required, can you modify the existing program in any way. How does the existing program hold its data etc

Comment: can you communicate directly to the database?

Comment: It can be done with the windows API, but really, really, no - it's mad. Does the product offer any API itself? Check with the vendor. Don't go arsing around in the database - you've no idea what you might screw up unintentionally, or the potential harm to his business that would ensue...

Comment: I can't modify the existing program in anyway it's a commercial program. Don't have direct access to the database no. :( Also No API i checked. I believe this is because they want you to buy another overpriced CRM module.

Comment: you can try using SendKeys to send data to textboxes, but it won't be pretty

Comment: Thank you for the SendKeys tip... I'll see what I can do D: when you say it won't be pretty do you mean....the code is complicated ooorr it has a very high chance its not even going to work?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get something working with [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/), though it would be a pretty horrible solution. (I mean the approach is horrible, not Ranorex, which is a pretty cool automated GUI testing tool)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm going to look into this and SendKeys

Comment: Ranorex will be much easier, but is pricey. You can get a 30 day trial to see if it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could look into [UISpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms727247%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's free and might be easier to use than `SendKeys`. I think MS are making it obsolete, but it might still fit your need.